# Merging Of Two data frame Having In between Date and Time in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, stat

**Data Frame -1**

```
   Date_Time<- c("6/13/2017 6:36",  "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:36",   "6/13/2017 6:37",   "6/13/2017 6:37",   "6/13/2017 6:37",   "6/13/2017 6:37",   "6/13/2017 6:37",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:38",   "6/13/2017 6:39",   "6/13/2017 6:39",   "6/13/2017 6:39",   "6/13/2017 6:39",   "6/13/2017 6:39",   "6/13/2017 6:39",   "6/13/2017 6:40",   "6/13/2017 6:40",   "6/13/2017 6:40",   "6/13/2017 6:40",   "6/13/2017 6:40",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:41",   "6/13/2017 6:42",   "6/13/2017 6:42",   "6/13/2017 6:42",   "6/13/2017 6:42",   "6/13/2017 6:42",   "6/13/2017 6:42",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:43",   "6/13/2017 6:44",   "6/13/2017 6:44",   "6/13/2017 6:44",   "6/13/2017 6:44",   "6/13/2017 6:44",   "6/13/2017 6:44",   "6/13/2017 6:44",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:45",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:46",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:47",   "6/13/2017 6:48",   "6/13/2017 6:48",   "6/13/2017 6:48",   "6/13/2017 6:48",   "6/13/2017 6:48",   "6/13/2017 6:48",   "6/13/2017 6:48",   "6/13/2017 6:49",   "6/13/2017 6:49",   "6/13/2017 6:49",   "6/13/2017 6:49",   "6/13/2017 6:49",   "6/13/2017 6:50",   "6/13/2017 6:50",   "6/13/2017 6:50",   "6/13/2017 6:50",   "6/13/2017 6:50",   "6/13/2017 6:50",   "6/13/2017 6:50",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:51",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:52",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:53",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:54",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:55",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:56",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:57",   "6/13/2017 6:58",   "6/13/2017 6:58",   "6/13/2017 6:58",   "6/13/2017 6:58",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 6:59",   "6/13/2017 7:00",   "6/13/2017 7:00",   "6/13/2017 7:00",   "6/13/2017 7:00",   "6/13/2017 7:00",   "6/13/2017 7:00",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:01",   "6/13/2017 7:02",   "6/13/2017 7:02",   "6/13/2017 7:02",   "6/13/2017 7:02",   "6/13/2017 7:02",   "6/13/2017 7:02",   "6/13/2017 7:02",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:03",   "6/13/2017 7:04",   "6/13/2017 7:04",   "6/13/2017 7:04",   "6/13/2017 7:04",   "6/13/2017 7:04",   "6/13/2017 7:04",   "6/13/2017 7:04",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:05",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:06",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:07",   "6/13/2017 7:08",   "6/13/2017 7:08",   "6/13/2017 7:08",   "6/13/2017 7:08",   "6/13/2017 7:08",   "6/13/2017 7:08",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:09",   "6/13/2017 7:10",   "6/13/2017 7:10",   "6/13/2017 7:10",   "6/13/2017 7:10",   "6/13/2017 7:10",   "6/13/2017 7:10",   "6/13/2017 7:10",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:11",   "6/13/2017 7:12",   "6/13/2017 7:12",   "6/13/2017 7:12",   "6/13/2017 7:12",   "6/13/2017 7:12",   "6/13/2017 7:12",   "6/13/2017 7:13",   "6/13/2017 7:13",   "6/13/2017 7:13",   "6/13/2017 7:13",   "6/13/2017 7:13",   "6/13/2017 7:13",   "6/13/2017 7:14",   "6/13/2017 7:14",   "6/13/2017 7:14",   "6/13/2017 7:14",   "6/13/2017 7:14",   "6/13/2017 7:14",   "6/13/2017 7:14",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:15",   "6/13/2017 7:16",   "6/13/2017 7:16",   "6/13/2017 7:16",   "6/13/2017 7:16",   "6/13/2017 7:16",   "6/13/2017 7:16",   "6/13/2017 7:16",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   "6/13/2017 7:17",   
              "6/13/2017 7:17", "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:18",   "6/13/2017 7:19",   "6/13/2017 7:19",   "6/13/2017 7:19",   "6/13/2017 7:19",   "6/13/2017 7:19",   "6/13/2017 7:19",   "6/13/2017 7:19",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:20",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:21",   "6/13/2017 7:22",   "6/13/2017 7:22",   "6/13/2017 7:22",   "6/13/2017 7:22",   "6/13/2017 7:22",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:23",   "6/13/2017 7:24",   "6/13/2017 7:24",   "6/13/2017 7:24",   "6/13/2017 7:24",   "6/13/2017 7:24",   "6/13/2017 7:24",   "6/13/2017 7:25",   "6/13/2017 7:25",   "6/13/2017 7:25",   "6/13/2017 7:25",   "6/13/2017 7:25",   "6/13/2017 7:25",   "6/13/2017 7:25",   "6/13/2017 7:26",   "6/13/2017 7:26",   "6/13/2017 7:26",   "6/13/2017 7:26",   "6/13/2017 7:26",   "6/13/2017 7:26",   "6/13/2017 7:27",   "6/13/2017 7:27",   "6/13/2017 7:27",   "6/13/2017 7:27",   "6/13/2017 7:27",   "6/13/2017 7:27",   "6/13/2017 7:27",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:28",   "6/13/2017 7:29",   "6/13/2017 7:29",   "6/13/2017 7:29",   "6/13/2017 7:29",   "6/13/2017 7:29",   "6/13/2017 7:29",   "6/13/2017 7:29",   "6/13/2017 7:30",   "6/13/2017 7:30",   "6/13/2017 7:30",   "6/13/2017 7:30",   "6/13/2017 7:30",   "6/13/2017 7:31",   "6/13/2017 7:31",   "6/13/2017 7:31",   "6/13/2017 7:31",   "6/13/2017 7:31",   "6/13/2017 7:32",   "6/13/2017 7:32",   "6/13/2017 7:32",   "6/13/2017 7:32",   "6/13/2017 7:32",   "6/13/2017 7:33",   "6/13/2017 7:33",   "6/13/2017 7:33",   "6/13/2017 7:33",   "6/13/2017 7:33",   "6/13/2017 7:33",   "6/13/2017 7:34",   "6/13/2017 7:34",   "6/13/2017 7:34",   "6/13/2017 7:34",   "6/13/2017 7:34",   "6/13/2017 7:34",   "6/13/2017 7:34",   "6/13/2017 7:35",   "6/13/2017 7:35",   "6/13/2017 7:35",   "6/13/2017 7:35",   "6/13/2017 7:35",   "6/13/2017 7:36",   "6/13/2017 7:36",   "6/13/2017 7:36",   "6/13/2017 7:36",   "6/13/2017 7:36",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:37",   "6/13/2017 7:38",   "6/13/2017 7:38",   "6/13/2017 7:38",   "6/13/2017 7:38",   "6/13/2017 7:39",   "6/13/2017 7:39",   "6/13/2017 7:39",   "6/13/2017 7:39",   "6/13/2017 7:39",   "6/13/2017 7:40",   "6/13/2017 7:40",   "6/13/2017 7:40",   "6/13/2017 7:40",   "6/13/2017 7:40",   "6/13/2017 7:40",   "6/13/2017 7:40",   "6/13/2017 7:41",   "6/13/2017 7:41",   "6/13/2017 7:41",   "6/13/2017 7:41",   "6/13/2017 7:41",   "6/13/2017 7:42",   "6/13/2017 7:42",   "6/13/2017 7:42",   "6/13/2017 7:42",   "6/13/2017 7:42",   "6/13/2017 7:42",   "6/13/2017 7:42",   "6/13/2017 7:43",   "6/13/2017 7:43",   "6/13/2017 7:43",   "6/13/2017 7:43",   "6/13/2017 7:43",   "6/13/2017 7:43",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:44",   "6/13/2017 7:45",   "6/13/2017 7:45",   "6/13/2017 7:45",   "6/13/2017 7:45",   "6/13/2017 7:45",   "6/13/2017 7:45",   "6/13/2017 7:46",   "6/13/2017 7:46",   "6/13/2017 7:46",   "6/13/2017 7:46",   "6/13/2017 7:46",   "6/13/2017 7:47",   "6/13/2017 7:47",   "6/13/2017 7:47",   "6/13/2017 7:47",   "6/13/2017 7:47",   "6/13/2017 7:47",   "6/13/2017 7:48",   "6/13/2017 7:48",   "6/13/2017 7:48",   "6/13/2017 7:48",   "6/13/2017 7:48",   "6/13/2017 7:48",   "6/13/2017 7:49",   "6/13/2017 7:49",   "6/13/2017 7:49",   "6/13/2017 7:49",   "6/13/2017 7:49",   "6/13/2017 7:50",   "6/13/2017 7:50",   "6/13/2017 7:50",   "6/13/2017 7:50",   "6/13/2017 7:50",   "6/13/2017 7:51",   "6/13/2017 7:51",   "6/13/2017 7:51",   "6/13/2017 7:51",   "6/13/2017 7:51",   "6/13/2017 7:51",   "6/13/2017 7:51",   "6/13/2017 7:52",   "6/13/2017 7:52",   "6/13/2017 7:52",   "6/13/2017 7:52",   "6/13/2017 7:52",   "6/13/2017 7:53",   "6/13/2017 7:53",   "6/13/2017 7:53",   "6/13/2017 7:53",   "6/13/2017 7:53",   "6/13/2017 7:53",   "6/13/2017 7:54",   "6/13/2017 7:54",   "6/13/2017 7:54",   "6/13/2017 7:54",   "6/13/2017 7:54",   "6/13/2017 7:55",   "6/13/2017 7:55",   "6/13/2017 7:55",   "6/13/2017 7:55",   "6/13/2017 7:55",   "6/13/2017 7:55",   "6/13/2017 7:55",   "6/13/2017 7:56",   "6/13/2017 7:56",   "6/13/2017 7:56",   "6/13/2017 7:56",   "6/13/2017 7:56",   "6/13/2017 7:57",   "6/13/2017 7:57",   "6/13/2017 7:57",   "6/13/2017 7:57",   "6/13/2017 7:57",   "6/13/2017 7:58",   "6/13/2017 7:58",   "6/13/2017 7:58",   "6/13/2017 7:58",   "6/13/2017 7:58",   "6/13/2017 7:58",   "6/13/2017 7:59",   "6/13/2017 7:59",   "6/13/2017 7:59",   "6/13/2017 7:59",   "6/13/2017 7:59",   "6/13/2017 7:59",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:00",   "6/13/2017 8:01",   "6/13/2017 8:01",   "6/13/2017 8:01",   "6/13/2017 8:01",   "6/13/2017 8:01",   "6/13/2017 8:01",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:02",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:03",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:04",   "6/13/2017 8:05",   "6/13/2017 8:05",   "6/13/2017 8:05",   "6/13/2017 8:05",   "6/13/2017 8:05",   "6/13/2017 8:05",   "6/13/2017 8:06",   "6/13/2017 8:06",   "6/13/2017 8:06",   "6/13/2017 8:06",   "6/13/2017 8:06",   "6/13/2017 8:06",   "6/13/2017 8:06",   "6/13/2017 8:07",   "6/13/2017 8:07",   "6/13/2017 8:07",   
              "6/13/2017 8:07", "6/13/2017 8:07",   "6/13/2017 8:07",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:08",   "6/13/2017 8:09",   "6/13/2017 8:09",   "6/13/2017 8:09",   "6/13/2017 8:09",   "6/13/2017 8:09",   "6/13/2017 8:10",   "6/13/2017 8:10",   "6/13/2017 8:10",   "6/13/2017 8:10",   "6/13/2017 8:10",   "6/13/2017 8:10",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:11",   "6/13/2017 8:12",   "6/13/2017 8:12",   "6/13/2017 8:12",   "6/13/2017 8:12",   "6/13/2017 8:12",   "6/13/2017 8:13",   "6/13/2017 8:13",   "6/13/2017 8:13",   "6/13/2017 8:13",   "6/13/2017 8:14",   "6/13/2017 8:14",   "6/13/2017 8:14",   "6/13/2017 8:14",   "6/13/2017 8:14",   "6/13/2017 8:14",   "6/13/2017 8:15",   "6/13/2017 8:15",   "6/13/2017 8:15",   "6/13/2017 8:15",   "6/13/2017 8:15",   "6/13/2017 8:15",   "6/13/2017 8:16",   "6/13/2017 8:16",   "6/13/2017 8:16",   "6/13/2017 8:16",   "6/13/2017 8:16",   "6/13/2017 8:16",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:17",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:18",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:19",   "6/13/2017 8:20",   "6/13/2017 8:20",   "6/13/2017 8:20",   "6/13/2017 8:20",   "6/13/2017 8:20",   "6/13/2017 8:20",   "6/13/2017 8:20",   "6/13/2017 8:21",   "6/13/2017 8:21",   "6/13/2017 8:21",   "6/13/2017 8:21",   "6/13/2017 8:22",   "6/13/2017 8:22",   "6/13/2017 8:22",   "6/13/2017 8:22",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:23",   "6/13/2017 8:24",   "6/13/2017 8:24",   "6/13/2017 8:24",   "6/13/2017 8:24",   "6/13/2017 8:24",   "6/13/2017 8:25",   "6/13/2017 8:25",   "6/13/2017 8:25",   "6/13/2017 8:25",   "6/13/2017 8:25",   "6/13/2017 8:26",   "6/13/2017 8:26",   "6/13/2017 8:26",   "6/13/2017 8:26",   "6/13/2017 8:26",   "6/13/2017 8:26",   "6/13/2017 8:26",   "6/13/2017 8:27",   "6/13/2017 8:27",   "6/13/2017 8:27",   "6/13/2017 8:27",   "6/13/2017 8:27",   "6/13/2017 8:28",   "6/13/2017 8:28",   "6/13/2017 8:28",   "6/13/2017 8:28",   "6/13/2017 8:28",   "6/13/2017 8:29",   "6/13/2017 8:29",   "6/13/2017 8:29",   "6/13/2017 8:29",   "6/13/2017 8:29",   "6/13/2017 8:29",   "6/13/2017 8:30",   "6/13/2017 8:30",   "6/13/2017 8:30",   "6/13/2017 8:30",   "6/13/2017 8:30",   "6/13/2017 8:30",   "6/13/2017 8:31",   "6/13/2017 8:31",   "6/13/2017 8:31",   "6/13/2017 8:31",   "6/13/2017 8:32",   "6/13/2017 8:32",   "6/13/2017 8:32",   "6/13/2017 8:32",   "6/13/2017 8:32",   "6/13/2017 8:33",   "6/13/2017 8:33",   "6/13/2017 8:33",   "6/13/2017 8:33",   "6/13/2017 8:34",   "6/13/2017 8:34",   "6/13/2017 8:34",   "6/13/2017 8:34",   "6/13/2017 8:35",   "6/13/2017 8:35",   "6/13/2017 8:35",   "6/13/2017 8:35",   "6/13/2017 8:35",   "6/13/2017 8:35",   "6/13/2017 8:36",   "6/13/2017 8:36",   "6/13/2017 8:36",   "6/13/2017 8:36",   "6/13/2017 8:36",   "6/13/2017 8:36",   "6/13/2017 8:37",   "6/13/2017 8:37",   "6/13/2017 8:37",   "6/13/2017 8:37",   "6/13/2017 8:37",   "6/13/2017 8:37",   "6/13/2017 8:37",   "6/13/2017 8:38",   "6/13/2017 8:38",   "6/13/2017 8:38",   "6/13/2017 8:38",   "6/13/2017 8:39",   "6/13/2017 8:39",   "6/13/2017 8:39",   "6/13/2017 8:39",   "6/13/2017 8:40",   "6/13/2017 8:40",   "6/13/2017 8:40",   "6/13/2017 8:40",   "6/13/2017 8:40",   "6/13/2017 8:40",   "6/13/2017 8:41",   "6/13/2017 8:41",   "6/13/2017 8:41",   "6/13/2017 8:41",   "6/13/2017 8:41",   "6/13/2017 8:42",   "6/13/2017 8:42",   "6/13/2017 8:42",   "6/13/2017 8:42",   "6/13/2017 8:42",   "6/13/2017 8:43",   "6/13/2017 8:43",   "6/13/2017 8:43",   "6/13/2017 8:43",   "6/13/2017 8:44",   "6/13/2017 8:44",   "6/13/2017 8:44",   "6/13/2017 8:44",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:45",   "6/13/2017 8:46",   "6/13/2017 8:46",   "6/13/2017 8:46",   "6/13/2017 8:46",   "6/13/2017 8:46",   "6/13/2017 8:47",   "6/13/2017 8:47",   "6/13/2017 8:47",   "6/13/2017 8:47",   "6/13/2017 8:47",   "6/13/2017 8:47",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:48",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:49",   "6/13/2017 8:50",   "6/13/2017 8:50",   "6/13/2017 8:50",   "6/13/2017 8:50",   "6/13/2017 8:50",   "6/13/2017 8:50",   "6/13/2017 8:51",   "6/13/2017 8:51",   "6/13/2017 8:51",   "6/13/2017 8:51",   "6/13/2017 8:51",   "6/13/2017 8:51",   "6/13/2017 8:52",   "6/13/2017 8:52",   "6/13/2017 8:52",   "6/13/2017 8:52",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:53",   "6/13/2017 8:54",   "6/13/2017 8:54",   "6/13/2017 8:54",   "6/13/2017 8:54",   "6/13/2017 8:54",   "6/13/2017 8:54",   "6/13/2017 8:55",   "6/13/2017 8:55",   "6/13/2017 8:55",   "6/13/2017 8:55",   "6/13/2017 8:55",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:56",   "6/13/2017 8:57",   "6/13/2017 8:57",   "6/13/2017 8:57",   "6/13/2017 8:57",   "6/13/2017 8:57",   "6/13/2017 8:58",   "6/13/2017 8:58",   "6/13/2017 8:58",   "6/13/2017 8:58",   "6/13/2017 8:58",   "6/13/2017 8:58",   "6/13/2017 8:59",   "6/13/2017 8:59",   "6/13/2017 8:59",   "6/13/2017 8:59",   "6/13/2017 8:59",   "6/13/2017 8:59",   "6/13/2017 8:59",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:00",   "6/13/2017 9:01",   "6/13/2017 9:01",   "6/13/2017 9:01",   "6/13/2017 9:01",   "6/13/2017 9:01")
Value=c(108,    108,    109,    106,    108,    107,    104,    108,    111,    108,    110,    109,    108,    108,    107,    104,    107,    107,    105,    104,    108,    110,    109,    111,    113,    114,    112,    112,    112,    111,    110,    112,    112,    112,    112,    111,    109,    108,    109,    111,    112,    111,    109,    108,    107,    108,    111,    110,    109,    109,    109,    109,    110,    113,    114,    111,    105,    100,    101,    102,    105,    103,    100,    99, 99, 99, 98, 97, 97, 95, 94, 92, 92, 91, 89, 89, 88, 87, 89, 87, 88, 89, 92, 94, 96, 97, 98, 97, 96, 95, 95, 95, 98, 98, 98, 98, 97, 96, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 94, 93, 92, 93, 92, 91, 91, 89, 88, 87, 86, 84, 83, 82, 81, 82, 84, 88, 89, 91, 88, 89, 92, 90, 88, 89, 90, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 97, 98, 92, 93, 94, 95, 98, 100,    98, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 95, 97, 98, 99, 103,    106,    109,    110,    114,    116,    121,    118,    117,    116,    115,    114,    111,    109,    109,    109,    109,    110,    109,    110,    112,    113,    115,    115,    116,    116,    112,    112,    115,    117,    118,    117,    117,    116,    113,    114,    112,    113,    109,    109,    109,    109,    109,    108,    108,    109,    110,    109,    104,    105,    102,    99, 97, 96, 94, 92, 91, 90, 88, 86, 86, 85, 85, 84, 84, 82, 82, 81, 80, 80, 78, 78, 77, 76, 75, 75, 77, 79, 82, 83, 85, 85, 86, 83, 82, 72, 73, 73, 82, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 71, 72, 73, 74, 76, 76, 76, 75, 74, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 74, 74, 75, 76, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 76, 75,
        75, 75, 83, 82, 80, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 82, 80, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 80, 80, 80, 79, 79, 78, 78, 79, 78, 79, 79, 81, 80, 80, 79, 78, 77, 78, 81, 81, 80, 80, 79, 79, 81, 80, 80, 79, 78, 78, 76, 73, 72, 73, 75, 74, 73, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 75, 70, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 72, 71, 72, 73, 72, 73, 72, 72, 71, 72, 73, 72, 73, 72, 69, 66, 65, 77, 80, 79, 79, 81, 80, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 78, 76, 75, 76, 74, 75, 76, 76, 75, 75, 75, 74, 74, 74, 74, 75, 74, 74, 73, 72, 73, 73, 73, 75, 74, 74, 74, 73, 74, 73, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 75, 77, 78, 78, 77, 77, 76, 75, 76, 75, 73, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 70, 71, 72, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 71, 72, 72, 72, 71, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 73, 72, 72, 71, 70, 71, 70, 71, 71, 70, 70, 71, 72, 72, 72, 71, 72, 71, 72, 73, 72, 71, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 76, 76, 77, 78, 78, 78, 80, 84, 85, 86, 88, 89, 89, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 94, 95, 97, 99, 99, 99, 98, 96, 95, 93, 93, 96, 98, 100,    100,    101,    102,    101,    104,    104,    103,    102,    106,    106,    105,    102,    102,    102,    101,    101,    101,    100,    100,    100,    100,    102,    103,    105,    105,    105,    105,    105,    104,    104,    102,    102,    101,    101,    100,    99, 99, 98, 98, 99, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 98, 97, 97, 97, 93, 91, 87, 85, 85, 85, 85, 84, 82, 82, 82, 81, 81, 80, 80, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 64, 63, 63, 62, 62,
        61, 62, 60, 59, 58, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 61, 61, 61, 60, 61, 60, 59, 60, 61, 63, 65, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 75, 77, 78, 80, 82, 82, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 90, 93, 95, 96, 101,    96, 97, 98, 99, 100,    105,    107,    108,    109,    110,    111,    112,    113,    114,    115,    116,    116,    112,    107,    107,    107,    106,    105,    104,    101,    101,    101,    100,    97, 97, 91,
        90, 89, 89, 89, 89, 88, 88, 87, 86, 83, 82, 79, 76, 76, 76, 75, 75, 75, 74, 75, 74, 74, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 73, 74, 73, 73, 73, 73, 72, 72, 73, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 71, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 71, 70, 69, 69, 68, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 68, 68, 60, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 71, 69, 69, 68, 67, 68, 66, 66, 66, 67, 68, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 65, 64, 62, 64, 64, 65, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 66, 65, 64, 63, 63, 69, 69, 68, 67, 65, 64, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 66, 66, 67, 67, 68, 68, 70, 71, 70, 67, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 68, 67, 67, 66, 65, 65, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 77, 76, 76, 71, 69, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 67, 67, 67, 67, 69, 69, 70, 70, 69, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 70, 70, 70, 70, 66, 65, 64, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 62, 63, 64, 67, 68, 68, 68, 67, 66, 66, 67, 69, 71, 74, 77, 78, 80, 82, 85, 87, 89, 91, 92, 94, 95, 95, 97, 98, 98, 96, 95, 94, 92, 91, 89, 86, 86, 85, 82, 81, 82, 80, 80, 80, 80, 78, 77, 76, 76, 80, 80, 78, 77, 76, 76, 76, 76, 72, 71, 70, 69, 69, 68, 68, 68, 68, 69, 70, 71, 71, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 76, 77, 78, 78, 79, 76, 76, 78, 78, 79, 81, 83, 83, 85, 84, 84, 85, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85)
df=data.frame(DT=Date_Time , Value =Value)
```

**Data frame-2**

```
Date_Time1 <-c("2017-06-13T01:39:00",   "2017-06-13T02:17:00",  "2017-06-13T02:23:00",  "2017-06-13T02:30:00",  "2017-06-13T03:19:00",  "2017-06-13T04:54:00",  "2017-06-13T21:48:00",  "2017-06-13T21:48:30",  "2017-06-13T21:51:00",  "2017-06-13T21:56:30",  "2017-06-13T22:01:00",  "2017-06-13T22:03:30",  "2017-06-13T22:11:00",  "2017-06-13T22:12:00",  "2017-06-13T22:27:00",  "2017-06-13T22:35:00",  "2017-06-13T22:50:00",  "2017-06-13T23:02:30",  "2017-06-13T23:18:30",  "2017-06-13T23:46:00")
sl <-c("sleep", "sleep",    "sleep",    "sleep",    "sleep",    "sleep",    "wake", "sleep",    "sleep",    "wake", "sleep",    "wake", "sleep",    "sleep",    "sleep",    "sleep",    "sleep",    "wake", "sleep",    "sleep")
seconds <- c(1290,  360,    420,    2940,   5700,   330,    180,    480,    1200,   270,    150,    510,    60, 3000,   480,    900,    750,    960,    1650,   2340)

df1=data.frame(DT1=Date_Time1 , s1 =sl , seconds = seconds)
```

*Description*
Here we have two data frame df and df1.
*df* has two columns namely  `Date Time` & `values`
second data frame `df1` has column `date_time1` ,`s1` & `seconds`.
**Expected Output**
On the bases of column `sl` of `df1` we want `Mean and median & Standard Deviation` of Column `Value` from `df` Based on Sleep and wake As shown Below.

[image]

**Detail Explanation :** we Want to Compute Mean and Median of Column `Values` from data frame `df` Where the `Date and time` of `df1` Lies `in between date and Time` of `df` data Frame .Because the date and Time are not Exactly Matching they are `In Between Time` In short `we need to identify the at time of sleep or awake` what was the `mean ,median & standard deviation`.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to first standardize your times into `POSIXt` (I'm assuming that's why you listed `lubridate` as a tag despite not using it). Other thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896883/merge-on-date-and-hour-range and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222181/how-to-merge-dataset-based-on-date-range.

Comment: Somewhere in your first `Date_Time` example object there's a typo that prevents me from reproducing it. Maybe you can `dput()` it or something?